# Android: When check box on one activity is clicked, make edit text on another activity visible

Tags: android

I am making a guest check in app. I want to have a fields page that has check boxes the user can select that has desired information the guests have to input when checking in, for example: guest name, guest phone number, signature, etc. When the check box is selected on one activity, I want to be able to input guest information on a new activity that has edit texts that become visible when each check box is selected. I have tried using setOnCheckedChangeListener but I am new to android app development and cant seem to get it working. I'm not even sure if i'm putting the code in the right activity xml file. Any help you can provide would be great!

Here is my guest.java code (which isnt my main activity)

```
package com.example.gena.ng;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Guest extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

CheckBox checkBox;
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guest);

    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox:

            if (isChecked == true) {
                editText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                editText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            break;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my activity_guest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.genagizzi.ng.Guest">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Guest Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my activity_fields.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.genagizzi.ng.fields"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Please select the fields you would like to be displayed and press done."
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:onClick="listOptionsCheck"
    android:text="Done"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Here you put the rest of your current view-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guest Name"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:checked="false"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Drop Off Contact Name"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:checked="false"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Drop Off Contact Phone Number"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:checked="false"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time Checked In"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:checked="false"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Signature Box"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:checked="false"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check In/Out Button"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
    android:checked="false"/>



<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pick Up Contact Name"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
    android:checked="false"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pick Up Contact Phone Number"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:checked="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sharedpreference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to store the value of `Checkbox` whether its selected or not.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefrence", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString("checkbox_value", "selected");
editor.commit();  // commit is important here.
```

On next activity retrieve the value from `sharedpreference` and set your logic there.

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = (shared.getString("checkbox_value", ""));
if(value!=null && value.equals("selected")){
    // Checkbox was selected
}
else{
    // Checkbox was not selected
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to implement this, i'm a beginner in java programming. So in my fields class with the check boxes will contain a method for example called savedPreferences containing the first code to store the value of the checkbox. But how is the value of the checkbox stored? where do I assign the checkbox to the id in the xml layout so it knows which checkbox to store?

Answer (score 0):

Once the checkbox get selected , obtain the value in a variable . While performing the intent send this variable along with that . On second page receive the variable and release the edit text based on selection .

Answer (score 0):

when you move to next activity then get the current state of check box and passed with intent using putExtra() and set the current state of checkbox (checked or unchecked) and get in to the second activity and perform the action based on this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the visibility of the Edittext in the second Activity.

you need to  remove the following code from the Guest Activity

```
if (isChecked == true) {
                editText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                editText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Step : 1

Create one static class like this

```
 class CheckBoxState {

    private static Boolean isVisible = false

    public static void setVisibility(Boolean value){
    isVisible = value;
    }

    public static Boolean getVisibility(){
    return isVisible;
    }

}
```

Step 2:

Save your state from Guest Activity

```
 if (isChecked ) {
               CheckBoxState .setVisibility(true)
            } else {
               CheckBoxState .setVisibility(false)               
            }
```

Step 3:

In your second activity oncreate do the following

```
 if (CheckBoxState .getVisibility()) {
                editText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                editText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```